# No me cargan las imágenes de mi proyecto Angular, al igual que no me funcionan bien las Rutas (Al momento de Desplegar mi proyecto en un IIS)

Tags: angular, iis

Estoy queriendo desplegar mi proyecto en Angular en un Internet Information Service 2009, soy muy novato en este tema, por lo que primeramente intente desplegar mi app de Angular mediante el comando ng build --configuration production  (Estoy usando Angular 16)
La carpeta que me genera el deploy (dist) la estoy copiando y pegando dentro de mi host IIS, dentro del directorio inetpub\wwroot\front-anomalias

Localmente cuando ejecuto el comando ng serve me cargan bien todas las imagenes que tengo dentro de la carpeta assets, pero cuando despliego mi App a través del IIS ya no me carga ninguna imagen, y tampoco me funciona la página al darle al botón de "refresh" o F5.
Me tira siempre el error 404 NOT FOUND

Intenté también hacer un deploy usando el comando ng build --configuration production --base-href /front-anomalias/  y metiendole un web.config así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Pero tampoco me dió resultado, y como soy nuevo en este tema de Deploy en Angular (Es mi primer proyecto) No sé en donde tengo que modificar para hacer que tome bien las rutas de las imágenes..

Este es mi app.routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'altaExpte',
    component: AltaExpedienteComponent
  },
  {
    path:'notificacion',
    component:NotificacionComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'CargarNuevoExpediente',
    component: CargarNuevoExpedienteComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'altaCaratula',
    component: AltaCaratulaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'nuevaCaratula',
    component: NuevaCaratulaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'altaAnomalias',
    component: AltaAnomaliasComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'nuevaAnomalia',
    component: NuevaAnomaliasComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'anomalia-expediente',
    component: AnomaliaExpedienteComponent
  },
  {
    path:'carga-manual',
    component:CargaManualComponent
  }, 
  {
    path: 'carga-imagenes',
    component: CargaImagenesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'email',
    component: EmailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

La estructura de mi proyecto en angular en donde guardo las imágenes es :

```
front-anomalias\src\assets
```

[image: Sc IIS1]

[image: imagen como debería verse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu regla tienes `<action type="Rewrite" url="./" />`

cambialo por `<action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />`

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
        </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

además mencionas que tienes tus imágenes en `front-anomalias\src\assets`

esto está bien pero a la hora de generar el "build" la carpeta "assets" queda en la raiz, entonces cuando referencies las imágenes en tu código debes hacerlo con "./assets/..."

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Hace tiempo que estoy con este problema... y me estaba rompiendo la cabeza con esto... 

No sabes cuanto te agradezco hermano!